# Action<> object as a parameter to function and using it

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, action

I have this function as a solution to traversing my treeview:

```
protected void PerformActionOnNodesRecursive(TreeViewNodeCollection nodes, Action<TreeViewNode> action)
{
    foreach (TreeViewNode node in nodes)
    {
        action(node);
        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            PerformActionOnNodesRecursive(node.Nodes, action);
    }
}
```

But what I couldn't understand is how do I implement my action or the required action for each node.

Can any one please tell me how to use this action object and define a custom action?

Comment: Like so: `PerformActionOnNodesRecursive(myNodes, (node) => { /* whatever you need to do */ });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You an call the `Action` like this:

```
PerformActionOnNodesRecursive(node.Nodes, (node) => node.SomeProperty = "123");
```

Or:

```
PerformActionOnNodesRecursive(node.Nodes, (node) => 
    {
        // you can place multiple statements here.
    });
```

Or:

```
PerformActionOnNodesRecursive(node.Nodes, (node) => CallSomeOtherMethod(node));
```

Some useful information on lambda expression can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Patrick , on digging further I learned that this technique must be used only when required as it consumes more time to execute. But indeed there is lot of convenience. Please correct me if I am wrong and also please suggest the right place where I can learn this the proper way. I am a self learner. Except for the C language I have never taken any classes. I learned all by books and pieces of information from internet which until recently wasn't regularly available to me, so you see there is a lot of deviation from the regular path.

Comment: @user50927: No problem. You can learn about lambda expression [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I thought I left it unaccepted and clicked it again. I have accepted it again.

Comment: @user50927: You keep switching accepted answers? Either one of them is marked as 'the' answer. Pick one, and stick with it.

Comment: I don't understand. I marked both because yours was the exact answer and the other was nearly the answer I wanted. I didn't know that I can't mark multiple answers.

Comment: You can't indeed. If you have the privilege to (15 rep), you can upvote both answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `Action` as follows:

```
PerformActionOnNodedRecursive(node, new Action(t => t.Text = "Test"));
```

Now every child node and the node itself will receive the Text "Test"

Comment: No need for a `new Action`. A lambda expression can be converted to an `Action`.